# MS Access If conditon to update only certain data

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query to update MS access table with True or false, Few lines also contains "-1" or "0", Now, I need a query to update Table only for "-1" or "0". Please note, I have 15 fields to be updated in same table with similar data ( -1 or 0). I am not able to give criteria because of 15 fields doesn't allow for criteria to look for  Or condition. Here is current query, which is taking long time to update table due to huge data.

```
UPDATE [2017 OpsData] 
SET [2017 OpsData].[FLG-ContProd] = 
    IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-ContProd]="-1","TRUE",
    IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-ContProd]="0","FALSE",
    IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-ContProd]="TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"))), 
[2017 OpsData].[FLG-OutOfScope] = 
    IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-OutOfScope]="-1","TRUE",
    IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-OutOfScope]="0","FALSE",
    IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-OutOfScope]="TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"))), 
[2017 OpsData].[FLG-Stabilize] = 
    IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-Stabilize]="-1","TRUE",
    IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-Stabilize]="0","FALSE",
    IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-Stabilize]="TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"))), 
[2017 OpsData].[FLG-FastTrack] = 
    IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-FastTrack]="-1","TRUE",
    IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-FastTrack]="0","FALSE",
    IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-FastTrack]="TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"))), 
[2017 OpsData].[FLG-FLR] = 
    IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-FLR]="-1","TRUE",
    IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-FLR]="0","FALSE",
    IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-FLR]="TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"))), 
[2017 OpsData].[FLG-MetSLA] = 
    IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-MetSLA]="-1","TRUE",
    IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-MetSLA]="0","FALSE",
    IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-MetSLA]="TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"))),
[2017 OpsData].[FLG-ReOpen] = 
     IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-ReOpen]="-1","TRUE",
     IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-ReOpen]="0","FALSE",
     IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-ReOpen]="TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"))), 
[2017 OpsData].[FLG-SpeakUp] = 
     IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-SpeakUp]="-1","TRUE",
     IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-SpeakUp]="0","FALSE",
     IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-SpeakUp]="TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"))), 
[2017 OpsData].[FLG-HIPAA] = 
     IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-HIPAA]="-1","TRUE",
     IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-HIPAA]="0","FALSE",
     IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-HIPAA]="TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"))), 
[2017 OpsData].[FLG-CSATBounce] = 
     IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-CSATBounce]="-1","TRUE",
     IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-CSATBounce]="0","FALSE",
     IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-CSATBounce]="TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"))),
[2017 OpsData].[FLG-CA-ENGLISH] = 
      IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-CA-ENGLISH]="-1","TRUE",
      IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-CA-ENGLISH]="0","FALSE",
      IIf([2017 OpsData].[FLG-CA-ENGLISH]="TRUE","TRUE","FALSE")));
```

Comment: Please try to make the question more minimal. See [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't understand what your question is. If you want to use multiple criteria, you can just nest `IIF` statements.

Comment: So the fields are all text type and can have values "True", "False", "-1", "0". If this is a one-time fix, could just do Find/Replace. Maybe should correct all the "True" and "False" entries to -1 and 0 and convert the field to yes/no type.

Answer (score 0):

String comparisons always take a long time. Adding an index on those fields "may help".

I'd be inclined to do two passes per column. One to mark the -1's as "TRUE"

```
UPDATE [2017 OpsData] 
SET [2017 OpsData].[FLG-ContProd] = "TRUE"
where [2017 OpsData].[FLG-ContProd] = "-1";
```

And then one to mark everything else as "FALSE"

```
UPDATE [2017 OpsData] 
SET [2017 OpsData].[FLG-ContProd] = "FALSE"
where [2017 OpsData].[FLG-ContProd] <> "TRUE";
```

You might also want to create a new column that's a true boolean (yes/no) and use that for future processing, which should be faster.

```
UPDATE [2017 OpsData] 
SET [2017 OpsData].[FLG-ContProdNew] = False;

UPDATE [2017 OpsData] 
SET [2017 OpsData].[FLG-ContProdNew] = True
where [2017 OpsData].[FLG-ContProd] = "-1"
or [2017 OpsData].[FLG-ContProd] = "Yes";
```

Comment: Could do one pass per column. `UPDATE [2017 OpsData] 
SET [FLG-ContProd] = IIf([FLG-ContProd]="-1", "TRUE", "FALSE") WHERE IsNumeric([FLG-ContProd])`

Comment: Thank you..i got the answer.. this helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

Probably not faster but is simpler structure:

`UPDATE [2017 OpsData] 
SET [FLG-ContProd] = IIf([FLG-ContProd]="-1" Or [FLG-ContProd]="TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE"),
[FLG-OutOfScope] = IIf([FLG-OutOfScope]="-1" Or [FLG-OutOfScope]="TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE"),
[FLG-Stabilize] = IIf([FLG-Stabilize]="-1" Or [FLG-Stabilize]="TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE"),
[FLG-FastTrack] = IIf([FLG-FastTrack]="-1" Or [FLG-FastTrack]="TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE"),
[FLG-FLR] = IIf([FLG-FLR]="-1" Or [FLG-FLR]="TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE"),
[FLG-MetSLA] = IIf([FLG-MetSLA]="-1" Or [FLG-MetSLA]="TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE"),
[FLG-ReOpen] = IIf([FLG-ReOpen]="-1" Or [FLG-ReOpen]="TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE"),
[FLG-SpeakUp] = IIf([FLG-SpeakUp]="-1" Or [FLG-SpeakUp]="TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE"),
[FLG-HIPAA] = IIf([FLG-HIPAA]="-1"," Or [FLG-HIPAA]="TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE"), 
[FLG-CSATBounce] = IIf([FLG-CSATBounce]="-1" Or [FLG-CSATBounce]="TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE"),
[FLG-CA-ENGLISH] = IIf([FLG-CA-ENGLISH]="-1" Or [FLG-CA-ENGLISH]="TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE");`